# Where is the 'GraphicsLayer.MouseUp' event in the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF?

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

[This ArcGIS Runtime SDK for WPF tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/add-graphics-and-text.htm) includes a code example towards the end:

```
<esri:GraphicsLayer … MouseUp="GraphicsLayer_MouseUp" … />
```

If I try to add this line to my XAML code, I am getting the error:

> *The property `MouseUp` does not exist in XML namespace `http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/runtime/2013`.*

Also, [according to the API reference documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference/html/Events_T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Layers_GraphicsLayer.htm) such an event does not exist.

I am courious why it is possible according to the tutorial? Does the event exist or not, and if so, how do I use it in my XAML?

I am using SDK version 10.2.3, same as the one referenced in the tutorial.

Comment: Well, that tutorial's title says "Beta", so perhaps the tutorial isn't really 100 % correct and things are still changing. I dare say if the event is not mentioned in the SDK reference pages, and it's *only* mentioned in the tutorial (which appears quite likely, judging from a quick Google search), and your experience tells you that the property isn't there, then the simplest explanation would be that the tutorial is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After stakx comment, I wrote to esri and got the following response:

> ...
>
> I’m afraid that was a relic from the way GraphicsLayer worked in the
>   first beta of our API, so no, there won’t be mouse events exposed on
>   the graphics layer. I’ll remove the selection section from the
>   graphics topic for now to avoid confusion.
>
> ...